# Core Data reloads only when I return to main view?

Tags: swift, swiftui, core-data

I have this issue that keeps bugging me - Core Data only loads my data whenever I return to the main view.

In my **Content View**, I perform a @FetchRequest

```
@Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc
@FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: []) var contracts: FetchedResults<Contract>
```

I loop through contracts to create a List.

ForEach (contracts, id: .self) {contract in

```
NavigationLink {
 DetailContract(contract: contract)
  } label: {
     ContractListRow(contract: contract)
  }
```

I pass the contract to the Detail View, into a variable of type FetchedResults.Element.

In the Detail View, I have a list, and each row of the list contains contract attributes. I **edit each row** via an .onTapGesture {} that shows a sheet, with a form.

```
@Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc
@State var contract: FetchedResults<Contract>.Element
@State var showEditContractNunber: Bool = false
@State var newContractNumber: String = ""

var body: some View {
    NavigationStack {
        List {
            Section {
                Text("Contract no. \(contract.registrationNumber ?? "")/\(contract.dateSigned ?? Date.now, formatter: formatData)")
                    .listRowSeparator(.hidden)
                    .fontWeight(.semibold)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        showEditContractNunber.toggle()
                    }
                    .sheet(isPresented: $showEditContractNunber) {
                        
                        NavigationStack {
                            Form {
                                TextField(contract.registrationNumber ?? "", text: $newContractNumber)
                            }
                            .navigationTitle("Edit")
                            .toolbar {
                                ToolbarItem (placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                                    Button {
                                        contract.registrationNumber = newContractNumber
                                        
                                        try? moc.save()
                                        
                                        showEditContractNunber.toggle()
                                        
                                    } label: {
                                        Text("Save")
                                    }
                                }
                                
                                ToolbarItem (placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
                                    Button("Cancel", role: .cancel) {
                                        showEditContractNunber.toggle()
                                    }
                                }
                                
                            }
                        }.presentationDetents([.fraction(0.4)])

[...]
```

The issue I keep having in all my views is that whenever I edit data or add an instance of an entity which is in relationship to Contract Entity, the **view refreshes only when I go up the view hierarchy**.

So, in my example, if I edit the contract number in the edit sheet, I will only see the new number after I return to Content View. And even in content view, I do not see the new number of the contract, I only see it in the Detail View, where I edited it.

I seem to experience this issue when **I create multiple entities**. If I only create one entity with a lot of attributes, the issue does not exist, it loads absolutely fine.

I also would like to mention that in a complex program, with a main view > second view > third view and so on, even if I have multiple entities in core data (such as contracts, invoices, clients, etc.), **I only perform a @FetchRequest in the Content View, and keep passing a FetchedResult.Element down the hierarchy**. If I need other entities, I call them as a contract attribute (contract.invoice?.invoiceNumber, for example).

I don't know if it is good practice or not, or if I should just perform a FetchRequest on every of the sub-views. If I were to fetch a list of elements on each view, I would have to filter them with a predicate to retrieve a ONE unique element...I don't know if it is possible.

Please help! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I guess sometimes a long and elaborate question has a simple answer...

When you pass an Element from a view to the next view, just use an @ObservedObject wrapper.

So, in my example, instead of `@State var contract: FetchedResults<Contract>.Element`, I should have written `@ObservedObject var contract: FetchedResults<Contract>.Element`, or even better,`@ObservedObject var contract: Contract`.

This is not written in the example, but I call @StateObject in the App SwiftUI view, on the Data Controller (NSPersistantContainer).

So in the App view:

```
@main
struct myApp: App {
    
    @StateObject private var dataController = DataController()
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environment(\.managedObjectContext, dataController.container.viewContext)
        }
    }
}
```

Where Data Controller is:

```
    class DataController: ObservableObject {
    let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "iLegal")
    
    init () {
        container.loadPersistentStores { description, error in
            if let error = error {
                print("Core Data failed to load: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                return
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

If you use @ObservedObject, the view will refresh no problem.

I hope this helps somebody...it was starring me in the face, but it kept me thinking for a day.

Cheers!